Unique constraint across tables
I have three tables: Songs, Artists, and Albums. The relationship between any two of the three is many to many, so I have three bridge tables: ArtistAlbums, ArtistSongs, and AlbumSongs.
For example, if artist X and album Y are in ArtistAlbums, then X is one of Y's authors. Similarly for ArtistSongs and AlbumSongs.
I want to ensure that certain table joins result in at most one row. Specifically, I need that there is only one song with the name X whose artists have names A and B. Similarly, there is only one album with the name Y whose artists have names A and B. (I haven't really begun to think about constraints across all three tables. But one possible constraint could be that, given any song, and any album of the song, at least one of the song's artists must be an artist of the album.) Is there a way to do this without using triggers?
The schema is:
create table artists (id uuid primary key, name text not null);
create table songs (id uuid primary key, name text not null);
create table albums (id uuid primary key, name text not null);
-- I have index on names for each table
create table artist_albums (
    artist_id uuid references artists(id) on delete cascade,
    album_id uuid references albums(id) on delete cascade,
    primary key (artist_id, album_id)
);

create table artist_songs (
    artist_id uuid references artists(id) on delete cascade,
    song_id uuid references songs(id) on delete cascade,
    primary key (artist_id, song_id)
);

create table album_songs (
    album_id uuid references album(id) on delete cascade,
    song_id uuid references songs(id) on delete cascade,
    primary key (album_id, song_id)
);

The name of artists/songs/albums by themselves need not be unique.

I don't think there is a good way to do that.

@LaurenzAlbe So can all this only be ensured by how the application inserts? Originally I was writing a procedure for this, but the procedure had race conditions because I had to check if a table join (matching a song and its artists by names) returns anything, then conditionally inserts based on if anything was returned.

I would enforce that in the application. You can do it in the database, but that requires the definition of redundant unique constraints that you can reference with foreign keys from a table on which you create a unique index. Not exactly pretty.

The relationship between any two of the three is many to many, so I have three bridge tables: ArtistAlbums, ArtistSongs, and AlbumSongs. This is not correct. You'd have relation song-to-album, and either artist-to-album or artist-to-(song-to-album). Relations cannot form a ring, they must form a tree.

@Akina The same song can be on many albums. The same song can be by multiple artists. The same album can have multiple artists. So a three part relationship is needed.

NO!!! The same song NAME but not the song itself.

I think you should just drop the table artist_albums completely. The m:n relationship between artists and albums is already implemented indirectly via the other two m:n relationships. Artists become authors of an album by contributing to a song. I don't see an easy way to enforce your desired unique constraint, though. Unique constraints only cover a single table. You would have to de-normalize the set of artists into an array column with deterministic sort order into the table songs to be able to do so. Lots of tricky details there ...

@ErwinBrandstetter The problem with dropping that table is some song's authors are featured artists, so a song in an album might have authors X and Y, but only author X of the song is also the author of the album. And yeah I don't think I would want to denormalize data like that, it's a bit too tricky

@Akina No, I'm not talking about SongName, I literally mean same instance of a song itself. Two artists can collaborate and be on the same song at the same time. And the same exact song itself can be released on multiple albums (such as Greatest Hits, etc, type of albums that come out after the original album).

Two artists can collaborate and be on the same song at the same time. In such case you'd have 2 separate rows in artist-to-(song-to-album) adjacency table. the same exact song itself can be released on multiple albums These will be 2 separate rows in song-to-album.

@Akina Ok, so we agree? OP's design is not wrong (logically), a "ring" (aka graph relationship) is ok. That's a snowflake schema then. Yes, a  schema with a "tree" relationship is more ideal when possible which then follows a star schema structure.

@Akina some artists of songs aren't an artist of the album, like a featured artist. so if we have an artist-to-(song-to-album) table, then we would need a separate table for ft-artist-to-song. Do you think that is a better design?

@Akina what if instead of artist-to-(song-to-album) table, we have album-to-(song-to-artist) table (and song-to-artist table)? then we can represent featured artists, and song can have multiple artists and be on multiple albums. An album's artists become the union of all artists referenced by album-to-(song-to-artist) table. Although one limitation of this is that a song's position in the table would ideally be in song-to-album table, but now that we don't have that, we have to denormalize.
But with this schema of album-to-(song-to-artist) in mind, is there a different answer to my question?
